# What are the minimum permissions I need to run New-Mailbox using powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I have a c# program runs PowerShell scripts connecting to Exchange Online using an Azure App/certificate to obtain its permissions.  I have set the Azure app to have the permission **exchange.manageAsApp**

For reference see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)

Picture of rights at the moment below
[image]

This seems to work well. However, as I understand it, this means that my app has full admin rights in exchange online which i'd like to restrict.

I need to read mailbox configuration from resource mailboxes.  i.e
`PowerShell get-mailbox -identity MyResource@domain.com`

Is there a way of further restricting rights to only the rights needed to read mailbox configurations?  If so how, and what is the minimum right needed?

I have tried removing the **exchange.manageAsApp** permission and just using
**mailboxsettings.read** but it seems that it needs the manageAsApp permission to work.

Thanks in advance.